# installing GGTS support for eclipse in ubuntu

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I am working on Grail/Groovy project just i wanted to use GGTS in eclipse mode and GGTS is not installing on the previously installed eclipse. The complete project is building in UBUNTU.

Comment: Can you share a few more information about which version of Eclipse you are using and what exactly happens when you try to install the GGTS components? Are you using the Eclipse Marketplace entry of GGTS? Or something else?

Comment: I am using eclipse-3.8, I am trying to install GGTS from eclipse market place. When i download the GGTS support for the previosly installed eclipse the downloaded will be 0mb size. and no otherway. Please go through the link for detailed understanding.

Comment: I don't know which link you mean, but what is the exact error message that you are seeing when using a fresh Eclipse, go to the Marketplace instal dialog, look for GGTS for Eclipse 3.8, and install that?

Comment: Thanks for the response martin, I got solution from my friend. But i am confuse with the grails project development can u suggest me to develop web application which uses menu like home, about us , contact us etc.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the issue. Would you mind sharing the solution here, so that others can benefit from that? That would be great. With regards to learning about Grails, I would recommend to go to: https://grails.org/learn

Comment: Sorry... im sharing the link below to install the grails/groovy tool suite.  (http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/09/spring-tool-suite-groovygrails-tool-suite-3-6-1-released/)  Use these three commands for complete installation of grails/groovy tool suite.